# CreateWindowW always returns null

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to C++ coding, and I'm trying to create a window using the Win32 API, but `CreateWindowW()` always return a NULL value. I tried to use `CreateWindowEx()` and `CreateWindow()`, but the same results.

Here is the code I used:

```
#include<windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Regesteration of Window Class had Failed", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    HWND x =  CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass",L"NEW Window",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,800,600,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if (!x)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Creation of Window Class had Failed", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
         
        default:
            DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can any one please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return ? _"...If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww

Comment: `return DefWindowProcW` when message is processed by default window procedure.

Comment: @RichardCritten : I don't know how to use GetLastError() But thank you anyway,

Comment: @rafix07 thank you for replying , it tried your solution and it really worked , I don't know why, I was doing exactly what an youtube coding channel instructor was doing and he didn't use **return DEfWindowProcW()**  as you did. Thank you very much that was very helpful

Comment: I double check what was the instructor was doing and he was doing it wright but I wasn't paying attention

Comment: "I don't know how to use GetLastError()". You have to plug this gap in your knowledge immediately or things are going to be very painful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window procedure *always* returns 0, which ultimately cancels window creation. As outlined in the documentation for [`CreateWindowExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw):

> The CreateWindowEx function sends [`WM_NCCREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate), [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize), and [`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-create) messages to the window being created.

The first message, `WM_NCCREATE`, has the following in the documentation:

> If the application returns `FALSE`, the [`CreateWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) or [`CreateWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) function will return a `NULL` handle.

`FALSE` has a value of `0`, so when your window procedure returns `0`, window creation is terminated. A call to `GetLastError` will usually also return `0` (i.e. no error) in this case.

You'll want to have your window procedure return the value returned by the call to `DefWindowProcW` instead, i.e.

```cpp
default:
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
```